# Change orders of rows in mysqli_result

Tags: php

For example I have the code

```
$query="Select * from table order by id";
$res1=mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
echo $row['Id'];
}

echo '<br>';

$query="Select * from table order by user";
$res1=mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
echo $row['Id'];
}
```

It is possible to do this without **second query** and without use of `array and foreach`, to change orders of row in `resul1` from **first query** to get order like in **second query**.

Comment: To what order you want to change it?

Comment: Use `Select * from table order by user` as a first query?

Comment: I need first and last result too.

Comment: I am interesting if is possible to change orders of row after executing query using the `resource` returned by `select`.

Comment: I try to make site and use very low number of queryes when compose  each page to use low resorces

Comment: @A-2-A `its better to research first before asking question` don't be bad. May be you here also will learn some think new today :)

Comment: I think it is not possible. Maybe you are interested in [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)?

Comment: to separate query with `;`?

Comment: @ fusion3k `I think it is not possible` - but why? I have this data in memory as `resorce` and I want to make changes on this data? PHP is so ... unconfortable

Comment: @ A-2-A `Asking many question don't make you good learner.` - yes but it can emprove my English, and may be I lost somethink when I read book or tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can easily order by several fields at one time:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id, user ";
$res1 = mysqli_query($link,$query);
....
```

Comment: Thank you, but it not return the same, I think!?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by passing a php variable in the mysql query.

```
 $query="Select * from table order by $order";
```

and set $order as you want.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id, user ";
```

This will order your data first by id and then user.

Comment: Thank you, but I also will make 2 queryes to DB, first with $order=id, second with $order=user. I understand you?

Comment: you can just pass the table and order by dynamically using php variable and this will be done only by one query

Comment: In the question you need to use order same as in second query

Comment: you are right, need to store $order for id and user and pass this in the query :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad English and low PHP knowledges don't permit to understand you. Can you be more explicite, please here `pass the table and order by dynamically using php variable `!?

Comment: you need to store orders in the $order variable like $order='id' and $order='user' and then use it after order by in the mysql query as i said above

Comment: If I use `ORDER BY id, user` it firs arange by id and las by user. And I will have for example (id|user): 7|7;8|4;9|9. By user is arranged haotic. I don't need this `ORDER BY id, user` only firs `ORDER BY id` and after do somethin by result to get `ORDER BY  user` without do query (and array/each function)

Answer (score 0):

You can change order of results in PHP.

1. Get all results into a PHP array.
2. Write a comparison function.
3. Use `usort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php